# Create Object from parsed cvs data in python

Tags: python

If I have a CVS file with rows of data and the row index was as below:

```
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

If I iterate the file, how could I then create an object from the data between 1-5, thus creating a new object for every 1-5 block of data ?

Comment: Is each group always exactly 5 rows, or is it however many rows until the index starts over at 1, or …?

Comment: PS, don't use the "code snippet" button, just the "code" button. A "code snippet" is for JavaScript code that runs right inside the question.

Comment: Sorry about using the code snippet button, and the rows are different lengths, with 1 being the start of the next block of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to treat every group of 5 rows as a separate object, that's a perfect job for the `grouper` function in the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

For example:

```
with open('spam.csv') as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    groups = grouper(rows, 5)
    for group in groups: # there will be 4 groups
        for row in group: # each one with 5 rows
            do_stuff(row)
```

---

If that "5" is just approximate, and the real rule is that every time the index starts over at 1, you start a new group, you can use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Or, if you want to understand how it works, first write it explicitly. For example:

```
with open('spam.csv') as f:
    group = []
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        if row[0] == '1':
             # new group, process the old group
             do_stuff(group)
             group = []
        group.append(row)
    # don't forget the leftover group at the end
    do_stuff(group)
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample, so how would I then parse until the next 1, creating, and then either create an object, or dict that can be saved as a temporary data file to be further parsed ?